# How to normalize URIs in Jersey 2?

Tags: jersey-2.0

What is the Jersey 2 equivalent of [FEATURE_NORMALIZE_URI](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#FEATURE_NORMALIZE_URI)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: It doesn't look like Jersey 2 has an equivalent feature, but it's quite simple to implement yourself:

```
/**
 * Normalizes incoming URIs.
 * <p>
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
@PreMatching
public class NormalizeUriFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        URI requestUri = requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri();
        URI normalized = requestUri.normalize();
        if (!requestUri.equals(normalized))
            requestContext.setRequestUri(normalized);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to `register()` the filter in your `Application`.